# Angular how to add more than 1 static (hardcoded) option to a <Select> dropdown

Tags: angularjs, list

Using ng-options as better than ng-repeat. 
Have a single-select drop-down, and a multi-select combo-box. Both are dynamically populated from server. Trying to add both two static . I already know how for ONLY ONE  at client side as:

```
<option value="">Whatever</option>
```

But only entry w/ value="" will be added, so this will drop the second one:

```
<option value="">Whatever1</option>
<option value="">Whatever2</option>
```

Besides a workaround to add them at server-side, is there a way to do it at client side? I've checked many post here not found the answer.

Comment: I assume that you are retrieving the data from your server in the form of a Promise. What you can do is inject the items into the data array in your controller's Promise success function.

Comment: @sheppe Sure this is another way.